# Drop down menus do not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The drop down menu on a site has ceased working correctly. The sub menus do not close up any more. Can anyone untangle this mess?

This is the website address;  https://www.wideboards.com

The menu code is as follows;

```js
var expandFirstItemAutomatically = false;
var initMenuIdToExpand = false;
var expandMenuItemByUrl = true;


var initialMenuItemAlwaysExpanded = false;

var pete_slidedown_menuObj;
var divToScroll = false;
var ulToScroll = false;
var divCounter = 1;
var otherDivsToScroll = new Array();
var divToHide = false;
var parentDivToHide = new Array();
var ulToHide = false;
var offsetOpera = 0;
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Opera') >= 0) offsetOpera = 1;
var slideMenuHeightOfCurrentBox = 0;
var objectsToExpand = new Array();
var initExpandIndex = 0;
var alwaysExpanedItems = new Array();

function TopMenusToShow() {
  var obj = divToScroll;
  var endArray = new Array();
  while (obj && obj.tagName != 'BODY') {
    if (obj.tagName == 'DIV' && obj.id.indexOf('slideDiv') >= 0) {
      var objFound = -1;
      for (var no = 0; no < otherDivsToScroll.length; no++) {
        if (otherDivsToScroll[no] == obj) {
          objFound = no;
        }
      }
      if (objFound >= 0) {
        otherDivsToScroll.splice(objFound, 0);
      }
    }
    obj = obj.parentNode;
  }
}

function showSubMenu(e, inputObj) {

  if (this && this.tagName) inputObj = this.parentNode;
  if (inputObj && inputObj.tagName == 'LI') {
    divToScroll = inputObj.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0];
    for (var no = 0; no < otherDivsToScroll.length; no++) {
      if (otherDivsToScroll[no] == divToScroll) return;
    }
  }
  hidingInProcess = false;
  if (otherDivsToScroll.length > 0) {
    if (divToScroll) {
      if (otherDivsToScroll.length > 0) {
        popMenusToShow();
      }
      if (otherDivsToScroll.length > 0) {
        autoHideMenus();
        hidingInProcess = true;
      }
    }
  }
  if (divToScroll && !hidingInProcess) {
    divToScroll.style.display = '';
    otherDivsToScroll.length = 0;
    otherDivToScroll = divToScroll.parentNode;
    otherDivsToScroll.push(divToScroll);
    while (otherDivToScroll && otherDivToScroll.tagName != 'BODY') {
      if (otherDivToScroll.tagName == 'DIV' && otherDivToScroll.id.indexOf('slideDiv') >= 0) {
        otherDivsToScroll.push(otherDivToScroll);

      }
      otherDivToScroll = otherDivToScroll.parentNode;
    }
    ulToScroll = divToScroll.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
    if (divToScroll.style.height.replace('px', '') / 1 <= 1) scrollDownSub();
  }


}



function autoHideMenus() {
  if (otherDivsToScroll.length > 0) {
    divToHide = otherDivsToScroll[otherDivsToScroll.length - 1];
    parentDivToHide.length = 0;
    var obj = divToHide.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    while (obj && obj.tagName == 'DIV') {
      if (obj.id.indexOf('slideDiv') >= 0) parentDivToHide.push(obj);
      obj = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    }
    var tmpHeight = (divToHide.style.height.replace('px', '') / 1 - slideMenuHeightOfCurrentBox);
    if (tmpHeight < 0) tmpHeight = 0;
    if (slideMenuHeightOfCurrentBox) divToHide.style.height = tmpHeight + 'px';
    ulToHide = divToHide.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
    slideMenuHeightOfCurrentBox = ulToHide.offsetHeight;
    scrollUpMenu();
  } else {
    slideMenuHeightOfCurrentBox = 0;
    showSubMenu();
  }
}


function scrollUpMenu() {

  var height = divToHide.offsetHeight;
  height -= 15;
  if (height < 0) height = 0;
  divToHide.style.height = height + 'px';

  for (var no = 0; no < parentDivToHide.length; no++) {
    parentDivToHide[no].style.height = parentDivToHide[no].getElementsByTagName('UL')[0].offsetHeight + 'px';
  }
  if (height > 0) {
    setTimeout('scrollUpMenu()', 5);
  } else {
    divToHide.style.display = 'none';
    otherDivsToScroll.length = otherDivsToScroll.length - 1;
    autoHideMenus();
  }
}

function scrollDownSub() {
  if (divToScroll) {
    var height = divToScroll.offsetHeight / 1;
    var offsetMove = Math.min(15, (ulToScroll.offsetHeight - height));
    height = height + offsetMove;
    divToScroll.style.height = height + 'px';

    for (var no = 1; no < otherDivsToScroll.length; no++) {
      var tmpHeight = otherDivsToScroll[no].offsetHeight / 1 + offsetMove;
      otherDivsToScroll[no].style.height = tmpHeight + 'px';
    }
    if (height < ulToScroll.offsetHeight) setTimeout('scrollDownSub()', 5);
    else {
      divToScroll = false;
      ulToScroll = false;
      if (objectsToExpand.length > 0 && initExpandIndex < (objectsToExpand.length - 1)) {
        initExpandIndex++;

        showSubMenu(false, objectsToExpand[initExpandIndex]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function initSubItems(inputObj, currentDepth) {
  divCounter++;
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  div.style.position = 'relative';
  div.style.display = 'none';
  div.style.height = '1px';
  div.id = 'slideDiv' + divCounter;
  div.className = 'slideMenuDiv' + currentDepth;
  inputObj.parentNode.appendChild(div);
  div.appendChild(inputObj);
  var menuItem = inputObj.getElementsByTagName('LI')[0];
  while (menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.tagName == 'LI') {
      var aTag = menuItem.getElementsByTagName('A')[0];
      aTag.className = 'slMenuItem_depth' + currentDepth;
      var subUl = menuItem.getElementsByTagName('UL');
      if (subUl.length > 0) {
        initSubItems(subUl[0], currentDepth + 1);
      }
      aTag.onclick = showSubMenu;
    }
    menuItem = menuItem.nextSibling;
  }
}

function initSlideDownMenu() {
  pete_slmenuObj = document.getElementById('pete_slidedown_menu');
  pete_slmenuObj.style.visibility = 'visible';
  var mainUl = pete_slmenuObj.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
  var mainMenuItem = mainUl.getElementsByTagName('LI')[0];
  mainItemCounter = 1;
  while (mainMenuItem) {
    if (mainMenuItem.tagName == 'LI') {
      var aTag = mainMenuItem.getElementsByTagName('A')[0];
      aTag.className = 'slMenuItem_depth1';
      var subUl = mainMenuItem.getElementsByTagName('UL');
      if (subUl.length > 0) {
        mainMenuItem.id = 'mainMenuItem' + mainItemCounter;
        initSubItems(subUl[0], 2);
        aTag.onclick = showSubMenu;
        mainItemCounter++;
      }
    }
    mainMenuItem = mainMenuItem.nextSibling;
  }

  if (location.search.indexOf('mainMenuItemToSlide') >= 0) {
    var items = location.search.split('&');
    for (var no = 0; no < items.length; no++) {
      if (items[no].indexOf('mainMenuItemToSlide') >= 0) {
        values = items[no].split('=');
        showSubMenu(false, document.getElementById('mainMenuItem' + values[1]));
        initMenuIdToExpand = false;
      }
    }
  } else if (expandFirstItemAutomatically > 0) {
    if (document.getElementById('mainMenuItem' + expandFirstItemAutomatically)) {
      showSubMenu(false, document.getElementById('mainMenuItem' + expandFirstItemAutomatically));
      initMenuIdToExpand = false;
    }
  }

  if (expandMenuItemByUrl) {
    var aTags = pete_slmenuObj.getElementsByTagName('A');
    for (var no = 0; no < aTags.length; no++) {
      var hrefToCheckOn = aTags[no].href;
      if (location.href.indexOf(hrefToCheckOn) >= 0 && hrefToCheckOn.indexOf('#') < hrefToCheckOn.length - 1) {
        initMenuIdToExpand = false;
        var obj = aTags[no].parentNode;
        while (obj && obj.id != 'pete_slidedown_menu') {
          if (obj.tagName == 'LI') {
            var subUl = obj.getElementsByTagName('UL');
            if (initialMenuItemAlwaysExpanded) alwaysExpanedItems[obj.parentNode] = true;
            if (subUl.length > 0) {
              objectsToExpand.unshift(obj);
            }
          }
          obj = obj.parentNode;
        }
        showSubMenu(false, objectsToExpand[0]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (initMenuIdToExpand) {
    objectsToExpand = new Array();
    var obj = document.getElementById(initMenuIdToExpand)
    while (obj && obj.id != 'pete_slidedown_menu') {
      if (obj.tagName == 'LI') {
        var subUl = obj.getElementsByTagName('UL');
        if (initialMenuItemAlwaysExpanded) alwaysExpanedItems[obj.parentNode] = true;
        if (subUl.length > 0) {
          objectsToExpand.unshift(obj);
        }
      }
      obj = obj.parentNode;
    }

    showSubMenu(false, objectsToExpand[0]);

  }



}
window.onload = initSlideDownMenu;
```

```css
#pete_slidedown_menu {
  width: 230px;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  width: 250px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth1 {
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth2 {
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #000000;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth3 {
  margin-top: 1px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #000000;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth4 {
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #000000
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth5 {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slideMenuDiv1 ul {
  padding: 1px;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slideMenuDiv2 ul {
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slideMenuDiv3 ul {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
}

#pete_slidedown_menu .slMenuItem_depth4 ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.style1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<a style="padding-left:25px; color:#008000;;" href="http://www.wideboards.com/Blog">
  <font size="4">Hardwood Blog</font>
</a>
<br /><br /><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/js/skypeCheck.js"></script>
<a href="skype:wideboards?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_white_124x52.png" style="border: none;" width="124" height="52" alt="Skype Me™!" /></a> <br>

<div id="pete_slidedown_menu">
  <!--Jobs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Personal Assistant</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Craftsmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Learners</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php"> Marketing / Computer Data 
              / Webpage-build Specialist</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Application_Form.php"> Application Form</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Recent Works -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Recent Works</strong></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Sycamore Sea</a></li>
        <li><a href="Ash_Sunburst.php">Ash Sunburst</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Huge Medallion</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">American Black Walnut</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Maple Star Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Handworked Sunburst</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Handworked Oak Boards</a></li>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Panelling Refinished</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Parquet -->
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Parquet</strong></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/What is Parquet.php">What is Parquet</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet.php">Parquet </a> </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Oak_Quarter_sawn.php">Quarter Sawn 
              Oak</a></li>
        <!--Sub Group-->
        <li><a href="#">Basketweave &raquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Basketweave.php">Basketweave</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Basketweave2.php">Basketweave2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End Sub Group -->
        <!-- Sub Group -->
        <li><a href="#">Panel Designs &raquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Designs.php">Parquet 
                  Panel Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Designs2.php">Parquet 
                  Panel Designs"</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End Sub Group -->
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Herringbone.php">Herringbone</a></li>
        <!-- Sub Group -->
        <li><a href="#">Parquet Borders &raquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Border_designs.php">Parquet 
                  Borders</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Border_designs_2.php">Parquet 
                  Borders 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End Sub Group -->
        <!-- Sub Group -->
        <li><a href="#">Photos &raquo;</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos.php">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos2.php">Photos2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos3.php">Photos3</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos4.php">Photos4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End Sub Group -->
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of First Group-->
  <!-- Marquetry -->

  <li><a href="#"><strong>Marquetry</strong></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry.php">What is Marquetry</a></li>
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="#">St. Petersburg&raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="St.Petersburg.php">Rooms</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_2.php">Borders</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_3.php">Medallions</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Eng 
                  grain</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Softwood 
                  </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Sub Group -->
    <!-- Sub Group -->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Design Drawings &raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs.php">Design 
                  Drawings</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_2.php">Design 
                  Drawings2</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_3.php">Design 
                  Drawings3</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Design 
                  Drawings4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="#">Marquetry Borders &raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Border_designs.php">Marquetry 
                  Borders</a></li>
          <li><a href="httpdocs/Marquetry_Border_designs_2.php">Marquetry Borders2</a></li>
          <li><a href="httpdocs/St.Petersburg_marquetry_borders.php">St. Petersburg 
                  Borders2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="#">Marquetry Examples&raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="recentworks.php">Sycamore Sea </a></li>
          <li><a href="http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/wideboards/AshParquetSunburstCircularFloor#">Ash 
                  Sunburst</a></li>
          <li><a href="httpdocs/St.Petersburg_marquetry_borders.php">St. Petersburg 
                  Borders2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Strips -->

  <li><a href="#"><strong>Strips</strong></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Ash_boards.php">Ash</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Beech_Boards.php">Beech</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Elm_Boards.php">Elm</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Jatoba_Boards.php">Jatoba</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Maple_Boards.php">Maple</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Boards.php">Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards.php">Walnut</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Boards -->

  <li><a href="#"><strong>Boards</strong></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Oak_Board_Prices.htm">Prices-Oak 
              Boards</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards_4.php#Ash">Ash</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Beech_Boards.php">Beech</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards_4.php#Blackbean">Blackbean</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Brown_Oak_boards.php">Brown Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Elm_Boards.php">Elm</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Jatoba_Boards.php">Jatoba</a></li>
      <li><a href="Yet_More_Boards_3.php">Lacewood</a></li>
      <li><a href="mesquite.php">Mesquite</a></li>
      <!-- New Sub Group -->


      <li><a href="#"><strong>Oak</strong> &raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Boards.php">Oak</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widewideboards.php">Very Wide 
                  Oak Boards</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/wideboards-in-Tunbridge-Wells.php">Very 
                  Wide Oak Boards in Kent</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/wideboards-in-chicago.php">Very 
                  Wide Oak Boards in Chicago</a></li>
          <li><a href="Wideboards_in_Cotswolds.php">Very Wide Oak Boards in 
                  Cotswolds</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/castleoak.php">Barn Oak Boards</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Country_Oak_Boards_1.php">Country 
                  Oak</a></li>
          <li><a href="Oak_Kilbees.php">15th Century Cottage </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End of Sub Group -->
      <!-- New Sub Group -->

      <li><a href="#"><strong>Walnut</strong> &raquo;</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards.php">American 
                  Black Walnut</a></li>
          <li><a href="AmericanWalnutPrices.php"> Prices American Black Walnut</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/French_Walnut.php">French Walnut</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End of Sub Group -->

      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Logs -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Logs</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widelogs.php">Wide Logs</a></li>
          <li><a href="httpdocs/widelogs2.php">More Logs</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widelogs3.php">Yet More Logs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Ancient Floors -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Ancient Floors</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Antique_Floors.php">Antique Floors</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Antique_Floors_Adams_Antiques.php">Antique Floors 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Woodblocks -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Woodblocks</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="httpdocs/oak_and_iron.php">Oak</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/end grain blocks.php">End Grain 
              Blocks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!--Restoration -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Restoration</strong></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="../Windsor.php">Windsor Castle</a></li>
          <li><a href="../Harewood.php">Harewood House</a></li>
          <li><a href="../Restorations.php">Parquet Restorations</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End of Group -->
        <!-- Bad Jobs -->
        <li><a href="#"><strong>Bad Jobs</strong></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Badjob.php">Bad Jobs Generally 
              </a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/BadjobCotswolds.php">Bad Job Cotswold</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <!-- End of Sub Group -->
    </ul>
    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Technical -->
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Technical</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Fixing methods.php">Fixing methods</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Choice of Timber">Timber 
          Choice</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Thickness">Thickness</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Wide Plank Flooring">Wide 
          Plank</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Storage of the timber">Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#expectations">Expectations</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Aclimatisation">Acclimatising</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#Prep">Preparation</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#Subfloors">Subfloors</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Shrinkage">Shrinkage 
          / Expansion</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/underfloor_heating.php">Underfloor 
          Heating</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/">Timbers</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Choice of Timber">Timber 
          Choice</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/underfloor_heating.php">Types</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Lacquers -->

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Lacquers</strong></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Water based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Thinners based</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spirit based</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- End of Group -->

</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  While you've posted a copious amount of code, I'd suggest you edit it down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - emphasis on minimal...  that's a lot of code to wade through.  Additionally, consider building a snippet so we can run it in place, or setting up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Also - may I suggest that you _dramatically simplify_ - javascript is no longer required to get drop-downs to work.  Your HTML appears to be structured properly, such that ditching the js and using just these two styles should get you started with a _much simpler_  drop-down menu: `#pete_slidedown_menu li ul { display: none; }  pete_slidedown_menu li:hover ul {display: block;}`

Comment: Did we have javascript 30 years ago?? Nope, it was invented in 1995. Though its a pretty old site. Wayback archive has first seen it in Oct 1999! https://web.archive.org/web/19990601000000*/www.wideboards.com

Answer (score 2):

and congrats on such an achievement in 1999.

I reviewed your code and have made alternative css (and dropped the javascript - but you will need it for your google translate element - i didn't put that in)

Have a look at the snippet. It could be refined by adding `.parent` classes to your upper ul groups. Basically what I did is put all of your grouped elements within `ul`, closed off any top elements that had unclosed `<li>` tags, and added some css (not a lot of it was needed, but like i say, you can add more if you like).

I hope this helps.

```css
ul li {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul>ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul>ul {
  display: none;
}

ul:hover>ul {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div id="pete_slidedown_menu">
  <!--Jobs -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Personal Assistant</a></li>
      <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Craftsmen</a></li>
      <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php">Learners</a></li>
      <li><a href="httpdocs/No%20Job%20vacancy.php"> Marketing / Computer Data 
              / Webpage-build Specialist</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Application_Form.php"> Application Form</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Recent Works -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Recent Works</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Sycamore Sea</a></li>
      <li><a href="Ash_Sunburst.php">Ash Sunburst</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Huge Medallion</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">American Black Walnut</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Maple Star Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Handworked Sunburst</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Handworked Oak Boards</a></li>
      <li><a href="recentworks.php">Panelling Refinished</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of Group -->
  <!-- Parquet -->
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Parquet</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/What is Parquet.php">What is Parquet</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet.php">Parquet </a> </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Oak_Quarter_sawn.php">Quarter Sawn Oak</a></li>
      <ul>
        <!--Sub Group-->
        <li><a href="#">Basketweave &raquo;</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Basketweave.php">Basketweave</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Basketweave2.php">Basketweave2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <ul>


        <li><a href="#">Panel Designs &raquo;</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Designs.php">Parquet 
                  Panel Designs</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Designs2.php">Parquet 
                  Panel Designs"</a></li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Herringbone.php">Herringbone</a></li>
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="#">Parquet Borders &raquo;</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Border_designs.php">Parquet 
                  Borders</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Border_designs_2.php">Parquet 
                  Borders 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Photos &raquo;</a></li>
        <ul>

          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos.php">Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos2.php">Photos2</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos3.php">Photos3</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Parquet_Panel_Photos4.php">Photos4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End Sub Group -->
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <!-- End of First Group-->
    <!-- Marquetry -->

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Marquetry</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry.php">What is Marquetry</a></li>
      <ul>
        <!-- Sub Group -->
        <li><a href="#">St. Petersburg&raquo;</a></li>

        <li><a href="St.Petersburg.php">Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_2.php">Borders</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_3.php">Medallions</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Eng 
                  grain</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Softwood 
                  </a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </ul>


  <!-- End Sub Group -->
  <!-- Sub Group -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Design Drawings &raquo;</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs.php">Design 
                  Drawings</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_2.php">Design 
                  Drawings2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_designs_3.php">Design 
                  Drawings3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Designs_4.php">Design 
                  Drawings4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End Sub Group -->
    <!-- Sub Group -->
    <ul>

      <li><a href="#">Marquetry Borders &raquo;</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Marquetry_Border_designs.php">Marquetry 
                  Borders</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/Marquetry_Border_designs_2.php">Marquetry Borders2</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/St.Petersburg_marquetry_borders.php">St. Petersburg  Borders2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- End Sub Group -->
      <!-- Sub Group -->
      <li><a href="#">Marquetry Examples&raquo;</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="recentworks.php">Sycamore Sea </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://picasaweb.google.co.uk/wideboards/AshParquetSunburstCircularFloor#">Ash Sunburst</a></li>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/St.Petersburg_marquetry_borders.php">St. Petersburg  Borders2</a></li>
      </ul>

    </ul>

    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Strips -->

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Strips</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Ash_boards.php">Ash</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Beech_Boards.php">Beech</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Elm_Boards.php">Elm</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Jatoba_Boards.php">Jatoba</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Maple_Boards.php">Maple</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Boards.php">Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards.php">Walnut</a></li>
    </ul>


    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Boards -->

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Boards</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Oak_Board_Prices.htm">Prices-Oak 
              Boards</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards_4.php#Ash">Ash</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Beech_Boards.php">Beech</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards_4.php#Blackbean">Blackbean</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Brown_Oak_boards.php">Brown Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Elm_Boards.php">Elm</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Jatoba_Boards.php">Jatoba</a></li>
      <li><a href="Yet_More_Boards_3.php">Lacewood</a></li>
      <li><a href="mesquite.php">Mesquite</a></li>
      <!-- New Sub Group -->

    </ul>

    <li><a href="#"><strong>Oak</strong> &raquo;</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Boards.php">Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widewideboards.php">Very Wide 
                  Oak Boards</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/wideboards-in-Tunbridge-Wells.php">Very 
                  Wide Oak Boards in Kent</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/wideboards-in-chicago.php">Very 
                  Wide Oak Boards in Chicago</a></li>
      <li><a href="Wideboards_in_Cotswolds.php">Very Wide Oak Boards in 
                  Cotswolds</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/castleoak.php">Barn Oak Boards</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Country_Oak_Boards_1.php">Country 
                  Oak</a></li>
      <li><a href="Oak_Kilbees.php">15th Century Cottage </a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End of Sub Group -->
    <!-- New Sub Group -->


    <li><a href="#"><strong>Walnut</strong> &raquo;</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Yet_More_Boards.php">American 
                  Black Walnut</a></li>
      <li><a href="AmericanWalnutPrices.php"> Prices American Black Walnut</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/French_Walnut.php">French Walnut</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End of Sub Group -->

    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Logs -->
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Logs</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widelogs.php">Wide Logs</a></li>
      <li><a href="httpdocs/widelogs2.php">More Logs</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/widelogs3.php">Yet More Logs</a></li>


      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Ancient Floors -->

      <li><a href="#"><strong>Ancient Floors</strong></a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Antique_Floors.php">Antique Floors</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Antique_Floors_Adams_Antiques.php">Antique Floors 2</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Woodblocks -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Woodblocks</strong></a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="httpdocs/oak_and_iron.php">Oak</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/end grain blocks.php">End Grain 
              Blocks</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!--Restoration -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Restoration</strong></a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../Windsor.php">Windsor Castle</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Harewood.php">Harewood House</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Restorations.php">Parquet Restorations</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- End of Group -->
      <!-- Bad Jobs -->
      <li><a href="#"><strong>Bad Jobs</strong></a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Badjob.php">Bad Jobs Generally 
              </a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/BadjobCotswolds.php">Bad Job Cotswold</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- End of Sub Group -->
    </ul>
    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Technical -->
    <li><a href="#"><strong>Technical</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Fixing methods.php">Fixing methods</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Choice of Timber">Timber 
          Choice</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Thickness">Thickness</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Wide Plank Flooring">Wide 
          Plank</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Storage of the timber">Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#expectations">Expectations</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Aclimatisation">Acclimatising</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#Prep">Preparation</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Technical.php#Subfloors">Subfloors</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Shrinkage">Shrinkage 
          / Expansion</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/underfloor_heating.php">Underfloor 
          Heating</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/">Timbers</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/Thick_or_Thin.php#Choice of Timber">Timber 
          Choice</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.wideboards.com/underfloor_heating.php">Types</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- End of Group -->
    <!-- Lacquers -->


    <li><a href="#"><strong>Lacquers</strong></a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Water based</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Thinners based</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Spirit based</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>


  <!-- End of Group -->
</div>
```

There's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/1f1r0dj0/) here and a [new one here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3pj1o8qr/) where i have added in some classes (but not added extra style to them) - if you want you can add extra style to the css, and you will have more control using the classes/ids. It was hard keeping track of all the menus in the HTML so apologies if the naming order is not consistent (but like I say, no extra style was added to the classes so it won't make a difference.. yet, anyway).

Comment: you can take out the '<strong>' tags actually, i didn't do it in the fiddle/snippet but the css will suffice to make the bold text..

Comment: I cannot express my thanks heartily enough for your and others help with this drop down menu.  I am about to implement the changes and will let you know how it goes.  In respect of Wayback records, I commenced building the web site by learning html. code back in 1988 but I don't think I adopted the wideboards.com domain until much later - which must have been 1999.

Comment: @Wideboards by the way the updated fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/3pj1o8qr/ I think it's better

Comment: I regret to say Rachel that these menus still do not work, plus I now have such a plethora of alternatives that i am just as confused a ever.  I have uploaded the 'edited' code of menu, css an .js but it still does not work. I looked at the .js fiddle. It partially works with the first item on the menu.  That opens and closes, but moving on to the second opens all the other top menus. I have no idea about what elements of the coding are carrying out the opening and closing of the menus.  I try to interrogate the web about this but never come up with an answer i can understand.